# Логика функции Math.random() и ее округления

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Вот класс:

```
class yprajnenie_9_14
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    int a, a2;
    a=10 + (int)(99*Math.random()); //Диапазон от 10 до 99 (двухзначные числа)
    a2 = a % 10; //Поиск числа единиц 

    if (a2 == 0) //Если число единиц равно нулю, вывести значение a на экран
      System.out.println(a);

    if (a2 != 0)  //Если число единиц не равно нулю, поменять значение a2 на ноль, после вывести a на экран 
    {
      a2 = 0;
      System.out.println(a);
    }
  }
}
```

Ожидаемо, что если функция Math.random() предоставит, например, 64, то на экран будет выведено "60", но выводит совершенно другое число. С чем это может быть связано,механикусы?

Comment: очередной случай, где заголовок вопроса связан с вопросом только общими буквами, но никак не смыслом. Ни округление, ни логика math.random в вопросе никак не затрагивают.ся

Comment: И, на всякий случай, предвосхищая следующий вопрос, диапазон у вас не 10–99, а 10–108.

Answer (score 0):

А с чего это вдруг ожидаемо, что выведет 60? Выводит `а` и это именно то случайное число, которое было сгенерировано.
`a2` приравняли к 0? Ну окей. Вот только `а2` не имеет ни малейшего отношения к `а`.